# ELMAH - ErrorSignal.Raise no stack info

Tags: elmah

I am catching an exception and logging it with ELMAH.

If I do not catch the exception and let the app YSOD, ELMAH logs the full stack trace. However when I catch and use `ErrorSignal.Raise(ex)`, I do not get the stack trace.

I also tried to no avail:

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new System.ApplicationException(exception.ToString(), exception));
```

Whassup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
                new System.ApplicationException(
                    exception.Message + exception.StackTrace, exception));
```

Comment: Color me stunned. Really. For the reasons outlined in my post, I'm going to have to downvote this -- you're not logging an exception with a full stack trace, you're logging an exception with a different exception's stack trace as its message. This may produce a result that looks mostly correct, but it's definitely only incidental, and based on antipatterns.

Answer (score 11):

You're using `ErrorSignal.Raise` with an unthrown exception that you've just `new`'d up. The stack trace gets populated when you throw the exception, so your unthrown exception won't have a stack trace. ELMAH, on the other hand, will catch the exception instance you're wrapping here -- which, if you look at it in the debugger, will in fact contain the stack trace, unlike the wrapping exception.

Instead of wrapping in a System.ApplicationException (which, by the way you should originally have [inherited from](http://weblogs.asp.net/erobillard/archive/2004/05/10/129134.aspx) and nowadays is [considered obsolete by the framework designers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2006/06/23/644822.aspx)), you should just raise the original exception you have caught.

As an interesting side note: Since the stack trace is populated when you throw an exception, this:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

will destroy the original stack trace, whereas

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    throw; 
}
```

will not (the latter bit will emit the CIL `rethrow` opcode which preserves the original stack trace).